# Use Linux Subsystem bash for Visual Studio Code integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the Linux subsystem enabled on my Windows 10 laptop, and I'm using Debian
I was able to use Cygwin as VS Code's integrated terminal, with the help of this guide:

[VS Code - Cygwin as Integrated Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061894/vs-code-cygwin-as-integrated-terminal/)

But I'm using OpenCV in some of my projects, and installing it on Cygwin is pretty tricky AFAIK. Can I use Debian's terminal as VS Code's integrated terminal?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you enabled Bash On Windows (WSL console) you should, with this config, be able to have the bash as VScode terminal:

`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\bash.exe",`

Comment: I tried but it couldn't find OpenCV. Is this bash.exe created immediately after enabling WSL? Does it have anything to do with Debian/Ubuntu/openSUSE apps in Microsoft Store?

Comment: - You might need to restart your computer to finalize the install of WSL. - Yes, but this config works with Ubuntu for me. The exe might be of a different name for Debian or SUSE.

Comment: I figured it out. I forgot I also had Ubuntu as default and that doesn't have OpenCV. I switched to Debian with wslconfig and it worked. Thanks.