# How to configure Visual Studio Code to debug with cygwin, cmake and gcc

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, cmake, cygwin

I have to use cygwin and cmake for the build of the release and debug.
(The cygwin package has all needed tools/libs for the build process (cmake, gcc, boost))

I've already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061894/vs-code-cygwin-as-integrated-terminal)
Which now allows me to run cmake and the build scripts inside the console of visual studio code and the executable is generated properly.

And I've already installed the extension C/C++ for Visual Studio Code.

But how to configure visual studio code for debugging?

Comment: I don't see why one wants to use Visual Studio to use something like cygwin. Visual Studio already has a linux project template which could compile/debug on your remote shell.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis OP's using VSC, not VS.

Answer (score 0):

After building via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061894/vs-code-cygwin-as-integrated-terminal), all you need for debugging is a launch.json of the following structure:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Starten",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/PATH_2_YOUR_DEBUG.exe",//This you need to define
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\cygwinPath\\bin\\gdb.exe",//This you need to define
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Automatische Strukturierung und Einrückung für \"gdb\" aktivieren",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Afterwards you can set a breakpoint in the source of PATH_2_YOUR_DEBUG.exe and press F5.