# VS Code generating windows-style path; cygwin git needs unix-style path -- fatal 'outside repository' error

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, cygwin

Migrating to Visual Studio Code, I'm having trouble with the way it generates git commands from the IDE (Source Control panel, + symbol to add to the repo). Getting errors like this:

[image: git fatal error message]

```
> git add -A -- C:\Projects\zwm\uniq.py
fatal: C:\Projects\zwm\uniq.py: 'C:\Projects\zwm\uniq.py' is outside repository at 
'/cygdrive/c/Projects/zwm'
```

Obviously I'm trying to use the version of `git` from Cygwin. Not having a problem finding git.exe, it's in the path. Git works fine if I just `add -A uniq.py` from a cmd window.

Can I get VS Code to generate cygwin-style **forward-slash paths**? Or stop using absolute paths for files in the repo? Can't seem to find anything in the settings that addresses this.

Would this be a "terminal" issue, in that VS Code must be opening a terminal session to run git?  This setting doesn't seem to make a difference: `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Cygwin"`.  Nor does [the setting in this promising answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70437350/673991): `"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": { "Cygwin": { ...`. I have not tried [this suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/186119) from from github, about setting `"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": { "bash (MINGW64-MSYS2)": { ...` although it seems to be talking about using the terminal with bash-style paths.

Or ... should I be using instead some other version of [git built for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) that accepts backslash-delimited paths?

Using Windows 11, VS Code 1.85.2, git 2.42.1.

UPDATE:  VS Code is smart enough to update the status of a file (from U to A) if I git-add the file manually. I can see git-show commands in the output window such as `git show --textconv :4x4word.py`.  So why is VS Code smart when issuing a git-show command, but **dumb when generating git-add**?

Comment: are you planning to compile under Cygwin or under Mingw ?

Comment: @matzeri I've never done either. I do mostly Python and JavaScript development. You're think of C or C++ compilation?

Comment: @matzeri ... although ... I may need Cython for a compute-bound task. Would that mean I'd need to compile and make that choice? Which do you recommend, and how would it impact my git problem?

Comment: Use git built for Windows. It accepts back-slash delimited paths, forward-slash delimited paths, and even mixed-slash delimited paths, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this shotgun answer to a pinpoint question may help: try running your VSCode inside the compatibility environment in which you are developing.

First, are you [wedded to CygWin](https://ericzhng.github.io/psn-blogs/blog/comparison-cygwin-mingw-wsl/)?

If not maybe checkout [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) or [mingw](https://www.mingw-w64.org/)?

Then you can (most likely) avoid the path problems altogether by:

- running [VSCode from cygwin](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/7sa4bp/setting_up_vscode_with_cygwin/) or
- running [VSCode from wsl](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) or
- running [VSCode with mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)